# Getting issue in adding cron expression to crontab from java and CLI

Tags: java, linux, scripting, cron

I am running the command below with is passing two argument to my script file(This below command is being constructed from java):

```
sh /home/accure/Desktop/scripts/cronhandler.sh "/home/accure/Desktop/scripts/pipeline.sh 028d8ccb-4c46-4e02-a9b0-3c97a383daaf" "* * * * */5"
```

Where `"/home/accure/Desktop/scripts/pipeline.sh 028d8ccb-4c46-4e02-a9b0-3c97a383daaf"` is the first argument and `"* * * * */5"` is the second argument which is basically a cron expression.

`cronhandler.sh` is my script file which contain this code:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]
then
    echo "Crontab with create & update functionality"
    command=$1
    cron_exp=$2
        echo "cron_exp=$cron_exp"
        echo "command=$command"
        cron_exp=`echo $cron_exp | sed 's/"//g' `
        command=`echo $command | sed 's/"//g' `
        echo "cron_exp=$cron_exp"
        echo "command=$command"
    if [[ "$cron_exp" != " " && "$command" != " " ]]
    then
                crontab -l | grep -q "$command"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
                        crontab -l | grep -v "$command" | crontab -
            echo "CRON entry deleted successfully.."
        else
            echo "CRON entry deletion failed."
        fi
                crontab -l | grep -q "$command" || (crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "$cron_exp $command") | crontab -
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "CRON entry added successfully.."
        else
            echo "CRON entry addition failed."
        fi      
    fi
fi
```

The error I'm getting while running the script is below. Actually it's listing out my files and folders from current working directory instead of adding the cron expression to cron tab.

> Crontab with create & update functionality cron_exp=* * * * */5
>   command=/home/accure/Desktop/scripts/pipeline.sh
>   028d8ccb-4c46-4e02-a9b0-3c97a383daaf cron_exp=14.5 LinkedList vs
>   ArrayList in Java-QWMyhFUtFHo.mp4
>   [57.64911004342139,10.407439861446619]
>   accure-facebook-parser-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   apache-tomcat-7.0.41 Core Java With OCJP_SCJP - Collections Part-11 _
>   Map _ Hashmap _ linked Hashmap-pSGvbJ7GJ68.mp4.part Desktop Documents
>   Downloads epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm How HashMap works in Java With
>   Animation!! whats new in java8 tutorial-c3RVW3KGIIE.mp4 ingester Java
>   interview - How Hashmap works -YR7Vp7HcAgs.mp4 jce_policy-8.zip
>   mongodata Music netbeans-7.4 NetBeansProjects Pictures Public quasar
>   robomongo-0.8.4-x86_64 sa softs solr-6.2.1 solr-6.2.1.tgz Templates
>   testdata UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8 Videos Vinod 14.5 LinkedList vs
>   ArrayList in Java-QWMyhFUtFHo.mp4
>   [57.64911004342139,10.407439861446619]
>   accure-facebook-parser-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   apache-tomcat-7.0.41 Core Java With OCJP_SCJP - Collections Part-11 _
>   Map _ Hashmap _ linked Hashmap-pSGvbJ7GJ68.mp4.part Desktop Documents
>   Downloads epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm How HashMap works in Java With
>   Animation!! whats new in java8 tutorial-c3RVW3KGIIE.mp4 ingester Java
>   interview - How Hashmap works -YR7Vp7HcAgs.mp4 jce_policy-8.zip
>   mongodata Music netbeans-7.4 NetBeansProjects Pictures Public quasar
>   robomongo-0.8.4-x86_64 sa softs solr-6.2.1 solr-6.2.1.tgz Templates
>   testdata UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8 Videos Vinod 14.5 LinkedList vs
>   ArrayList in Java-QWMyhFUtFHo.mp4
>   [57.64911004342139,10.407439861446619]
>   accure-facebook-parser-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   apache-tomcat-7.0.41 Core Java With OCJP_SCJP - Collections Part-11 _
>   Map _ Hashmap _ linked Hashmap-pSGvbJ7GJ68.mp4.part Desktop Documents
>   Downloads epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm How HashMap works in Java With
>   Animation!! whats new in java8 tutorial-c3RVW3KGIIE.mp4 ingester Java
>   interview - How Hashmap works -YR7Vp7HcAgs.mp4 jce_policy-8.zip
>   mongodata Music netbeans-7.4 NetBeansProjects Pictures Public quasar
>   robomongo-0.8.4-x86_64 sa softs solr-6.2.1 solr-6.2.1.tgz Templates
>   testdata UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8 Videos Vinod 14.5 LinkedList vs
>   ArrayList in Java-QWMyhFUtFHo.mp4
>   [57.64911004342139,10.407439861446619]
>   accure-facebook-parser-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   apache-tomcat-7.0.41 Core Java With OCJP_SCJP - Collections Part-11 _
>   Map _ Hashmap _ linked Hashmap-pSGvbJ7GJ68.mp4.part Desktop Documents
>   Downloads epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm How HashMap works in Java With
>   Animation!! whats new in java8 tutorial-c3RVW3KGIIE.mp4 ingester Java
>   interview - How Hashmap works -YR7Vp7HcAgs.mp4 jce_policy-8.zip
>   mongodata Music netbeans-7.4 NetBeansProjects Pictures Public quasar
>   robomongo-0.8.4-x86_64 sa softs solr-6.2.1 solr-6.2.1.tgz Templates
>   testdata UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8 Videos Vinod */5
>   command=/home/accure/Desktop/scripts/pipeline.sh
>   028d8ccb-4c46-4e02-a9b0-3c97a383daaf CRON entry deletion failed.
>   "-":2: bad minute errors in crontab file, can't install. CRON entry
>   addition failed.

Note: Rather being added to crontab, `*` in cron expression is listing out my files and folder from current working directory.

Java code from where i am calling the command line is given below :

String pipelineFilePath="sh /home/accure/Desktop/scripts/pipeline.sh 028d8ccb-4c46-4e02-a9b0-3c97a383daaf";

```
        String cronExp="* * * * */5";

        pipelineFilePath = "\"" + pipelineFilePath + "\"";

        cronExp = "\"" + cronExp + "\"";

        command = "sh " + /home/accure/Desktop/scripts/cronhandler.sh + " " + pipelineFilePath + " " + cronExp;

        runScript(command);

        public void runScript(String script) throws InterruptedException {
        final String cmd = script;
        Thread runScript = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
                CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(cmd);
                executor.setExitValue(1);
                int exitValue = executor.execute(commandLine);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    });
    runScript.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`) around your arguments:

```
sh /home/accure/Desktop/scripts/cronhandler.sh '/home/accure/Desktop/scripts/pipeline.sh 028d8ccb-4c46-4e02-a9b0-3c97a383daaf' '* * * * */5'
```

It will prevent your shell's [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html).

Comment: Thanks Ronan..but this shell command i am getting from java code which i s being executing through command line and if i put single quotes then it will not allow to pass a argument. Is there any thing i can do with cronhandler script file ?

Comment: No. Your script has nothing to do with this. It gets the arguments after your shell's filename expansion. You can't know in your script that you originally had a `*`. Can you add your Java code to the question so I can help you?

Comment: Added ...It just constructing the script and calling the command line

Comment: What about adding single quotes like this? `command = "sh " + /home/accure/Desktop/scripts/cronhandler.sh + " '" + pipelineFilePath + "' '" + cronExp + "'";`